# How to route/redirect to a full url

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular 7 app.
In this app I want to redirect to a full url (coming from a DB). I want to redirect "within" the app so I do not have to do a full refresh of the page.

I tried this one but it did not work:

```
this.router.navigate([item.url]);
```

Comment: Can you try `this.route.navigateByUrl(item.url)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const url = new URL(item.url);
this.router.navigateByUrl(url.pathname);
```